Editing passwords in Vim/Neovim: How do I disable swap, backup, undo, etc files from command line
From time to time I need to edit sensitive files, for instance files that contain passwords or certificates. To avoid Vim leaking sensitive information, is there a way invoke Vim/Neovim so that Vim only touches the edited file during that invokation? No changes or creation of backup, swap, undo or other files?

I clarified what I mean by "other file creation or changes". I am hoping for a reply that is vim-specific, I hope vim will allow me to control it well enough without needing to use a heavy-weight solution like a sandbox for this.

So... you're asking for vim +"set nobackup backupcopy=no noundofile noswapfile"?

If that is all it takes, make it into an answer and I will upvote. A simple answer is a good thing!

To disable backup, undo and swap files as well as the backupcopy functionality, you can (un)set those option from the command line as follows:
vim +"set nobackup nowritebackup noundofile noswapfile viminfo=" a_sensitive_file

See :help 'backup', :help 'undofile', :help 'writebackup', :help 'swapfile' and :help 'viminfo' for reference and the options' implications. See :help -c for information on how to execute Ex commands from the command line (in this case, the :set command).
You may also be interested in :help encryption - not in the encryption feature itself - there are hints on how to edit files containing sensitive information.
You can create an alias for the command above or put them into a vimrc file, e.g. secure.vim and do
vim -u /path/to/secure.vim a_sensitive_file

This will :source only the options in secure.vim to initialize Vim (see :help -u). You may be left without your favorite colorscheme and plugins.
Disclaimers:

I may have missed something, of course. If one of those Bond villains gets hold of the nuclear codes, it's still your fault!
Depending on what else is in your Vim setup (I'm thinking of plugins, mainly), there may be other options you will have to switch off. We have GitHub Copilot for Vim these days, what better way to keep your data save than to broadcast it to an AI?


I have been poking around a bit, including setting up an inotifywait on my configured .vim-directory as well as the XDG local, config and cache directories (inotifywait -mr -e modify -e attrib -e close_write -e move -e create -e delete -e unmount .vim .local/ .config/ .cache/). I think backupcopy=no is for something else, the option we want is nowritebackup. However, if you have full-disk encryption the nobackup option might be enough: With writebackup on, vim makes a temporary copy while writing the file to protect against crashes, but the backup is always deleted after writing.

You're right. The value of backupcopy doesn't matter if nowritebackup is set. I'll edit. If you have full-disk encryption, you can likely do without any of these. You were the one to ask about paranoidly not writing any files :-)

A bit more checking gave this result: If you put it all in a function, you can call that function even after opening a file and all the swap-file, backup and undo files will be deleted.

Generally speaking, I like to keep my sensitive files encrypted on top of full disk encryption, I like to need a password every time I read a sensitive file. Full disk encryption makes me safe if my laptop is stolen, but there are many other dangers to look out for.

Well, deleted files can be restored... files that have never been written, can't. It all comes down to finding options you're comfortable with. Feel free to post an answer of your own with whatever solution you'll settle on.

I think your answer is perfect after the edit. As you say, it depends on what you are most afraid of and your threat level. The detail on nowritebackup is in the comments, if anyone is very curious. If we missed something let's hope they add a comment about it as well, so we can continue to build on the answer.
